# The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/maventestproject/target/test-classes/com'."

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I am facing the below issue frequently in my project in eclipse which disturbing developing the test scripts.Please help me in resolving this.

The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/maventestproject/target/test-classes/com'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent    maventestproject        Unknown Java Problem

Comment: Check that you haven't opened (in an editor  for instance) any files from the "/maventestproject/target/test-classes/com" folder , because this could lock the file and prevent the directory from being deleted.

Comment: I have not opened any files from the "/maventestproject/target/test-classes/com" folder.i tried refreshing and cleaning the project.still error remains.

Comment: In Windows? I have faced similar problem (and found no solution) that target directory was occasionally not deleted (event I have made sure no Explorer/cmd prompt/text editor etc is opening anything under target/).  Re-invoking mvn clean will work though

Comment: this worked for me.thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project and click Run As > MVN clean.
2. Make sure that target is empty if not manually delete the target folder. Hope this issue will be fixed.

Comment: Thank you.but if i delete target folder,if i want to see any project related results of maven it would be difficult i feel

Comment: Every time you build your project target will be created .MVN clean will surely help otherwise delete target folder manually.